# MongoDB count gives no output

Tags: json, database

MongoDB count syntax
I need to count entries >20
This code gives no output

```
db.student.count({"age">20})
```

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an aggregation pipeline as below:

```
db.student.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        age: {
          $gt: 20
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $count: "students_count_gt_20"
    }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used incorrect query syntax. So you are getting no records. Below query will help you to retrieve the count of all the records who have the age>20.

```
let query={
    age:{
        $gt:20
    }
}
```

Here you can also use **db.collection.countDocuments()** if you need only count of the documents as **db.collection.count()** method is depricated.

```
db.student.countDocumnets(query)
```